# Control multiple PCs with single Mouse and Keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, desktop

As a programmer I found it very hard to use my laptop and workstation with two different input devices, Can anyone suggest a good solution to use single mouse and keyboard to control my two machines

I am not looking for a Virtual Machine or RDP solution to see my machines in a single monitor,

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: It's not, but it's something loads of programmers are going to run into, making it a valuable question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Synergy.](http://synergy-foss.org/)

> *Synergy lets you easily share a single mouse and keyboard between
>   multiple computers with different
>   operating systems, each with its own
>   display, without special hardware.
>   It's intended for users with multiple
>   computers on their desk since each
>   system uses its own monitor(s).
>   Redirecting the mouse and keyboard is
>   as simple as moving the mouse off the
>   edge of your screen. Synergy also
>   merges the clipboards of all the
>   systems into one, allowing
>   cut-and-paste between systems.
>   Furthermore, it synchronizes screen
>   savers so they all start and stop
>   together and, if screen locking is
>   enabled, only one screen requires a
>   password to unlock them all.*

P. S.

See also [how to fix Synergy problems on Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fixing-problems-with-synergy-on-windows-vista/).

Comment: Is this product is Vista compatible?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fixing-problems-with-synergy-on-windows-vista/

Comment: Nice. Much better than the KVM solution I adopted.

Comment: This is the definitive application, to my knowledge. Excellent, and supports cut and paste if I remember right.

Comment: Synergy+ (synergy-plus) is something you may also want to try - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy%2B

Comment: Synergy cost money to buy now

Answer (score 8):

What you want is a small gadget called a [KVM switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) (keyboard, video and mouse switch). Googling for that term will hook you up with plenty of suppliers.

There is also a neat software solution called [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) that lets you use your cursor and keyboard input over multiple computers connected by a network.

Comment: Seems like the only real solution if you have an in-house closed network and also an internet box like I do.  Synergy looks good but (of course) requires network connectivity.

Comment: I've found KVM switches to be ideal to control multiple servers in a single room, sharing monitor, keyboard and mouse between them all - when you have a mixture of Linux and Windows boxen (in different versions!), on different network segments, this hardware approach is the only real answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another vote for Synergy for a software KVM solution.  I'm not sure about the others, but it's unique if your computers are running different operating systems. It worked very well when I had a W2k/Linux setup across 3 computers.

Answer (score 2):

Synergy is great, but also give something like VNC a try: it consolidates not only the keyboard and mouse but also the screen. In my case my desktop monitor is much larger than my laptops, and I'm more comfortable facing forward anyway (not looking off to the side where the laptop is.)

There is a lag compared to using a KVM switch, but no loss in video quality.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience Synergy is the best way to merge multiple monitors.

Others include:
- x2vnc
- x2x
- win2vnc
- osx2x
- win2x

... pretty much just take what OS/platform you're on, which one you want to connect to, and put a '2' in the middle. Type that into google and you're good2go.

Answer (score 2):

For my linux machine I use [QuickSynergy](http://quicksynergy.sourceforge.net/) since it provides a gui for easier configuration. It also has a Mac OS version.

Answer (score 1):

The best...

[Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll put in another vote for Synergy, but with a caveat - setup can be a little tricky. The first time I tried it, I could move my cursor over to another PC but I couldn't move it back.  Spend some time with the [documentation](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/running.html) before you proceed.

Answer (score 1):

**[InputDirector](http://www.inputdirector.com/)** is better than Synergy.  Here's why...

1. It has **built-in AES encryption** functionality (without requiring you to install OpenSSH) for secure transfer of input between machines.
2. It allows cut & paste of text **and files** between machines (by automatically translating to C$ and D$ shares)
3. Based on extensive use with a laptop, it is far more **reliable and stable** than Synergy when reconnecting after undocking & docking.  Synergy would frequently just stop working after docking and undocking, requiring me to kill it, restart it, and reconnect.  InputDirector rarely has any issues.
4. The configuration UI is **easier to use**, and has **more options**, than Synergy.
5. Lots of little things, like matching of cursor location between machines during screen-edge transitions, and overriding mouse settings of "Slave" machines with those of the "Master" machine.

Beyond that, as far as I can tell, it does everything Synergy does.  There's only a Windows version, but apparently it's also Vista compliant as well.

I've used both tools extensively, first Synergy, and then InputDirector.  InputDirector is just a more robust application.  It has all the features of Synergy and then some, plus the key ones listed above.  It's website isn't as attractive, and while it isn't GNU GPL'd like Synergy, it free nonetheless, and an oustandingly well-functioning tool.

Comment: Synergy+ attempts to fix these issues :)

Comment: Input Director is compatible with linux

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a KVM switch, but lately I've started running all my computers as virtual machines on a single hardware platform.  Each "system" is a window on my desktop!

Comment: But I mainly want different screen, so seeing it inside a single desktop is not good when I do designing

Answer (score 0):

I have a triple monitor display, and I just remote desktop into my other machines. I have 2-3 laptops on my desk at any given time, and 3 servers to administer. Over a 1 gbps connection, I have very little latency to worry about, and I can be working on three computers at once without much trouble. This may or may not help you, but I thought I would throw it in there for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean: two machines on your desktop, a lot of places use KVM-style switches.

They come in legacy PC-style and also USB. The USB version works with Macs and PCs.

My experience is that the small desktop switches are a bargain, and if you learn the keyboard shortcuts, you'll jump back and forth without much problem.

The machine room, 3-level tree KVM's are also pretty useful. They flake out more often, but when you have 60 machines, you simply can't have 60 pairs on input devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second Zarkonnens comment about [KVM Switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvm_switch) as I use one for this purpose all the time.  However I might share some rather frustrating experiences with them:

I have found that PS/2 interfaces tend to be somewhat more reliable on KVM switches than USB - I have had very bad experiences with some supposedly upmarket DVI-USB KVM kit from [Gefen](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=3113) and [Avocent](http://www.avocent.com/SwitchView_DVI_4-port.aspx).  Due to a quirk of my [Viewsonic](http://www.viewsonic.com/products/desktopdisplays/lcddisplays/proseries/vp2030b/) monitor where it would drop back to analog most of the time these were exacerbated to the point of the system being nearly unusable.

DVI and USB are finicky.  DVI monitors will often time out and sleep if they get no signal.  The KVM switch will assume that there is no monitor if it is not active, which will then be passed back to the video card.  USB interfaces will also get put to sleep randomly.

The net effect of this was that it was very difficult to get two machines to boot up and work on the KVM switch and the switch would lose keyboard or mouse input on one or both machines every few days.  This was followed by an hour or more of trying to get all of the hardware to come up and play nicely.  I got the same issue with the Avocent and Gefen switches on several different machines.

My older [Belkin VGA/PS2 kit](http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatSectionView.process?Section_Id=206977) worked fine with the Viewsonic monitors on VGA but I spent nearly £1000 on switches and cabling to try and get a working DVI-USB KVM setup.

In the end I got two [HP LP2065](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/uk/en/sm/WF05a/382087-382087-64283-444767-444767-1815933.html) screens that didn't have the bug that the Viewsonics exhibited.  These have two DVI inputs and I used one of my older Belkin PS/2 switches to switch the keyboard and mouse.  The computers are plugged directly into the monitor and the monitor's input selector is used to pick the computer.  The keyboard and mouse are switched off the KVM switch.  This is the setup that I'm using today.

The monitors and KVM have to be switched individually but it's much more reliable than the DVI-USB KVM switches that really did not work at all.  Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out [Multiplicity](http://www.stardock.com/products/multiplicity/) from Stardock.